# What does recourse mean in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

What does recourse mean in the following sentence:

> Here in Brazil we like games and have little recourse.

I don't know what that means in that sentence because according to the Cambridge Dictionary recourse means:

> using something or someone as a way of getting help, especially in a difficult or dangerous situation.

Comment: That is a strange sentence. What's it from? I imagine the speaker/writer may be Brazilian and not a native English speaker :)

Comment: Can you please  give additional context here, or perhaps link to the source? This seems to be an unusual usage.

Comment: from a youtube comment

Comment: I suspect that it means  **provision** / **access to facilities**

Comment: As a non-native speaker I may interpret it as: `Here in Brazil we like games, but have no or little possibility to get them.` Constructions like this one are often used in Russian.